# Android XML Error[collapsing bar issue after collapse]

Tags: android, xml, material-design, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This is what it looks like in emulator:

[image]

This is what it is supposed to looks like:

[image]

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:contentScrim="@color/accent"
        android:background="@color/oil">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/back_drop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/adminHomeInputOrigin"
                android:hint="Origin"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/adminHomeInputDestination"
                android:text="Destination"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adminHomeInputOrigin"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clientHomeSearchDate"
                android:text="Depture Date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adminHomeInputDestination"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Itinerary"
                android:id="@+id/clientHomeMyIt"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:onClick="ClientHomeViewClientItinerary"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Profile"
                android:id="@+id/clientHomeViewProfile"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clientHomeSearchDate"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:onClick="ClientHomeViewClientProfile"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clientHomeDepDateError"
                android:hint="error here"
                android:layout_below="@+id/clientHomeViewProfile"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="314dp"
            android:id="@+id/clientHomeListView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/accent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/clientHomeSearch"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:onClick="ClientHomeSearch"
    app:rippleColor="@color/primary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It looks like the colour does not appear and also the floating action bar is not displaying the image I want. Can someone tell me what goes wrong?

Comment: post your build.gradle file also @SamMinWong

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to use two coordinatorlayout. Try to replace it with some layout

Comment: @SamMinWong you should not add details about your question in the answer section...you could edit your question and post the same details over here..

Comment: @SamMinWong are you still facing the same issue?asking because i replicated the exact same xml on my machine and i am getting the intended outcome.